# How to change all the package easily?

Tags: intellij-idea

I copy util package from other project to my project.

But all the java files' package is still the previous package path, so it is wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw2sa.jpg)

See the upper snapshot, all the file under the util folder I copied from other project is still the `com.jackov.common.util`, how can I easily change the package to correct package instead of modify one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy them to the original package they were in the old project (create it in the new project), then use Refactor | Move to move them to another package (or Rename the package). IDE will update all the imports automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty solution:

`Edit > Find > Replace In Files`

Find: `package old.package.name`

Replace: `package new.package.name`

Select `In Project`

Press Enter.

Comment: Update: now it's "Replace in Files"